# Do I need to change password of Windows service after account password change?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have Windows 10, with a service running on it.

It service has been configured to run using a local user account.

If the user changes password for that account, does the user need to reconfigure the service with the new password?

PS: I created the service using nssm, and then changed it to use the local user account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the service is running with a local account, you need to update its password.